# Create an S3 bucket that sends notification to SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am trying to create a s3 bucket that sends notification to a SNS topic every time an object is dropped in the s3 bucket. My S3 bucket is called `foo-bucket` and my SNS topic is called `foo-topic`. I know how to setup this in aws console but i am having trouble when trying to do this via cloudformation.

This is the code i currently have

```
Resources:
  SNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: foo-topic
  SNSTopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: MyTopicPolicy
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: Statement-id
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: s3.amazonaws.com
          Action: sns:Publish
          Resource:
            Ref: SNSTopic
          Condition:
            ArnLike:
              aws:SourceArn:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                  - Ref: S3Bucket
      Topics:
      - Ref: SNSTopic
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: foo-bucket 
      AccessControl: BucketOwnerFullControl
      NotificationConfiguration:
        TopicConfigurations:
        - Topic:
            Ref: SNSTopic
          Event: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
```

I try to deploy the above and cfn rollsback due to the following error

> Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service:
> Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID:
> fooooo; S3 Extended Request ID: foooid; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [example cloudformation](https://bitbucket.org/gusto2_/my-samples/src/master/nodejs/node-aws-sample/elearn-infra-cf.yaml) creating a bucket, sns topic and a notification configuration. As already mentioned, you need to ensure proper dependency order.

The notification configuration doesn't check for the resource existence, so we need to use the `DependsOn` property to do so

As well be aware of potential circular reference, when creating an SNS Topic Policy. I defined the bucket name as a string, not reference. It allows to create an SNS with its policy before the notification config of the bucket.

```
  IngestionBucketDev:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn:
     - IngestionTopicDev
     - IngestionTopicPolicy
    Properties: 
      BucketName: "ingestion-codebucket-7832df8b-dev"
      NotificationConfiguration:
        TopicConfigurations:
         -  Topic: !Ref IngestionTopicDev
            Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                 - Name: suffix
                   Value: ".json"
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
           
               
  IngestionTopicDev:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: 
      TopicName: "elearn-ingest-topic"
      DisplayName: "elearn-ingest-topic"
      
  IngestionTopicPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties: 
      Topics:
       - !Ref IngestionTopicDev
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - 'sns:Publish'
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Ref IngestionTopicDev
            Principal: 
              Service: "s3.amazonaws.com"
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
               "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::ingestion-codebucket-7832df8a-dev"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, your problem is dependencies ;)

I had the same issue, if you don't specify a dependency order, like create SNS first then get the ID created withe REF in the Bucket part you will get a problem about destination configurations.

Please follow this link to fix your problem, you will see the `DependsOn` :

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: but it looks like i am creating thins in correct oder, snstopic,snstopicpolicy,s3bucket. Can you tell me what i exactly need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: There is no order of creation following the order  ressources in Yaml , I mean if you put SNS first then S3 in you yaml, CloudFormation will try to create them in parallel, so you must add a dependson to have to work, 
See the link posted .

Comment: @Unknowntiou, is it clear ?

Comment: @Hatim The DependsOn is not always enough. Creating an S3 notification, aws checks if there is a permission to send a message.  When having an S3 reference in the policy config, according to the dependency graph, cf first tries to create the S3 and then the topic policy and the SNS topic will not have the policy applied. Putting only DependsOn will create a circular dependency.

Comment: @gusto2, thank you for your feedback, exactly, the missing part is the resource policy to be created also and mentioned as dependency not just the DependsOn  ! perfect thank you for this information